# Assembly language, why isn't the jumps working? (JC)

Tags: assembly

I was trying to implement this algorithm

Add two numbers data1 and data2
if carry flag is set, jump to "add2digits"
if carry flag is not set, jump to "add1digit"

What happened is that if the sum is less than 100 (carry flag is NOT set), it still jumps to "add2digits".

My problem is how to implement this? 
I tried tweeking the code by exchanging JNC and JC, but the result is either one is working or the other.

heres the code:

```
;For adding 1 digit numbers
          mov ah, data1[0002]
          add ah, data2[0002]
          JC add2digits
          JNC add1digit
```

> add1digit:              mov sum, ah

```
          sub sum, 30h



          jmp afteradding

add2digits:   
          ;for adding 2 digit numbers
          mov ah, data1[0002]
          mov al, data1[0003]
          sub ax, 3030h
```

Comment: 100? Are you supposed to be working with decimal math here or regular math?

Comment: Can you give some examples of `data1[0002]` and `data2[0002]` for which you think it doesn't work properly?